# C#: Close Application When Service Stops

Tags: c#, service

I developed a service in C# that uses HttpListener.
When I stop the service, the process remains open for a while.
If I restart the service, it crashes (probably because the port is used).

How can I stop the process immediately when the service stops (via net stop) or at least wait for the process to finish before I start the new one.

this is the relevant code snippet:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        thread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

Comment: That is not the relevant code snippet. The relevant part is the code for `Listen`

Answer (score 0):

Your OnStop method needs to take some action that halts the Listen thread. You can do this in a few ways:

- Move the 'thread' object scope higher up so you can 'abort' the thread from OnStop (This is a BAD way of doing it)
- Whatever is in Listen needs to be notified in some way that it should stop 'Listening' and exit its thread. The simplest way would be a 'stopping' variable somewhere that you set to true that the Listening thread looks for but as Scott rightly says a cancellationToken would be more appropriate., In addition you need to use the Stop() method on the HttpListener.

Comment: Note, if you are going to set a variable make sure you mark it `volitile` or it is possible that the loop never will read the new value. A better option IMHO is pass in a `CancelationToken` and have the loop check on that.